# C++ gdb: Program received signal SIGABRT

Tags: c++, gdb

Here's the message when I run the program through gdb.

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00000003fd51373c in cygstdc++-6!_Znwm () from /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000003fd51373c in cygstdc++-6!_Znwm () from /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I have no idea how to go about debugging this error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say you overwrite your stack somewhere, obliterating the return address in the process. Judging by the backtrace comment `(corrupt stack?)`, gdb says i'm in good company on that. Call-depth breakpoints are a decent next step (i.e. made it here, made it here, made it here...).

Comment: Can you post code or is there too much of it?

Comment: There's too much, I'm trying breakpoints like WhozCraig said, and I'll see if I can isolate the error.